# How to mix Bootstrap .well and .button classes?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I want to mix Boostrap's .well and .button classes. If I try to do this, with default button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default well well-sm">Default-well</button>
```

In's looking amazing for me. But if I try with primary button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary well well-sm">Primary-well</button>
```

It looks a little bit weird. Does anybody try to do it and knows a solution to mix a non-default Bootstrap buttons with .well classes? JSFiddle is here: [JSFiddle for well and Bootstrap buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y55S/), there you can  see that .btn-default looks pretty well but .btn-primary behave bad.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to combine them?  `.well`s are meant as containers, `.btn` are, well, for buttons (which by definition are not really containers).  The reason `.btn-default` looks ok is because `.btn-default` adds little extra styling.  Not so with `.btn-primary` - is there any reason you want to combine these two?

Comment: @blurfus because it looks very well - "inset" without hover, "outset" on hover.

Comment: If it is only looks, why not then maybe create your own? (or override conflicting defaults with your own).  It would be shorter syntax, fewer tags and page loads faster - combining containers for buttons does not seem semantically right...

Comment: @blurfus You are right (and I don't think before about .well meaning, I thought it is simple style class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wells are not meant to be used in this way, rather they are meant to frame content with a slighty different background color and a little padding.

Looking at .well from twitter bootstrap's less you can see what it actually does:

```
well {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: @well-bg;
  border: 1px solid @well-border;
  border-radius: @border-radius-base;
  .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05));
  blockquote {
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  }
}

// Sizes
.well-lg {
  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: @border-radius-large;
}
.well-sm {
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: @border-radius-small;
}
```